# How to fix Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'?

Tags: mysql, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, quasar, node.js-fs

I started SSR with Quasar. And I am at the database stage. But I have changed modules, still nothing!
The suggestions are to do the following :

```
"browser": {
   "fs": false,
   "crypto": false
   //...
}
```

[image]

Temporarily the problem is solved at loading. But as soon as I try to connect, the console gives me `undefined` which I think is logical because of the `false` values put everywhere.
So my question is the following is **How to make a successful MySQL connection with Quasar?**
Thanks in advance.